# Can I make an MUI Accordion take up space in a stack when closed but float when open?

Tags: javascript, material-ui

Here's an example which is close to what I'm trying to do:

```
const H = ({children}) => {
  return <Typography variant="h1">{children}</Typography>
}

const App = () => {
  return <Stack sx={{height: '100vh'}}>
    <Paper><H>Item 1</H></Paper>
    <Paper sx={{flexGrow: 1}}><H>Item 2</H></Paper>
    <Paper><H>Item 3</H></Paper>
    <Accordion>
      <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMore/>} id="accordion-header">
        <H>Item 4</H>
      </AccordionSummary>
      <AccordionDetails>
        Subitem 1<br/>
        Subitem 2<br/>
        Subitem 3<br/>
      </AccordionDetails>
    </Accordion>
  </Stack>
};
```

When the `Accordion` is closed, the four items in the `Stack` take up all the available vertical space, with the second `Paper` taking up any extra space.  This is what I want.  But when the `Accordion` is open, I want the three `Paper` elements to stay the same size and the `Accordion` to float up over the top of them.  Is there a way to achieve this?